# Scrapy installation in Ubuntu: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: attrs

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I installed scrapy by following the tutorial [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html), the installation was success but once I try to setup a project by it shows

```
pip install Scrapy
nikhil@nikhil:~$ scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: attrs
nikhil@nikhil:~$ pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: attrs
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:: command not found
```

Any idea about how to solve this error ..? I couldn't find any useful pointers via Google.

Answer (score 2):

It means you need this resource.just install it.

```
pip install attrs
```